# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer prohibited in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, avfoundation, tvos

I wonder if anyone has any information why AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer is marked as "__TVOS_PROHIBITED"?

I don't want to write something ironic here, but the fact that video rendering on a TV-device is prohibited is kind of fun.

Comment: you have using onle tvOS or with other language like iOS of swift?

Comment: In IOS it's not prohibited however compiling the same code, target tvOS it's prohibited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tvOS version 10.2 is finally allowing the use of AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer in Apple TV devices.

(tvOS 10.2 is currently in beta when writing this post).